# ARM Assembly error message: free(): invalid next size (fast)

Tags: assembly, arm64

I am writing an assembly program that needs to call c's calloc to allocate memory for an array, change data in that array, then call free to free that memory at the end of the program. However, when I run the tests for this program, I get the error message: free(): invalid next size (fast). I am not sure how to fix this error in assembly.

I know that I need to have both calloc and free in my program as to not leak memory. This is my code:

```
.text

.global life

//
// life iteration calculator
// x0 - int *cells
// w1 - int width in words
// w2 - int height in rows
// 1. create dummy array
// 2. loop through each bit
//   a. get bit
//   b. find all 8 neighbor bits and add their values to a counter
//   c. perform set bit to correct value based on counter value
//   d. move to next bit
// 3. set original array values to the dummy array values and return
//
life:
    stp x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x19, x20, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x21, x22, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x23, x24, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x25, x26, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x27, x28, [sp, #-16]!

    // save original values into registers
    original .req x19
    mov original, x0
    width .req w20
    mov width, w1
    height .req w21
    mov height, w2
    dummy .req x22
    num_bits .req w23
    size .req w24
    mul size, height, width

    // create the array to insert updated values using calloc
    lsl w7, width, #5
    mul w7, w7, height
    mov num_bits, w7

    mov w0, size
    //mul w0, height, width   // w0 = height * width
    mov w1, #4    // w1 = 4
    bl calloc

    mov dummy, x0

    // initialize the dummy array
    mov x0, dummy
    mov w1, num_bits
    bl initialize

    // change values of dummy array using neighbor counts
    mov x0, dummy
    mov w1, num_bits
    mov x2, original
    mov w3, width
    bl edit_dummy

    // copy dummy values into original array
    mov x0, original
    mov x1, dummy
    mov w2, num_bits
    mov w3, width
    bl copy_values

    mov x0, dummy
    bl free

    b life_return

life_return:
    stp x27, x28, [sp], #16
    stp x25, x26, [sp], #16
    stp x23, x24, [sp], #16
    stp x21, x22, [sp], #16
    stp x19, x20, [sp], #16
    stp x29, x30, [sp], #16

    ret

    .unreq original
    .unreq width
    .unreq height
    .unreq dummy
    .unreq num_bits
    .unreq size

// set up a loop call to iterate through the original array of cells 
// start by initializing the dummy array to all 1's
initialize:
    stp x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x19, x20, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x21, x22, [sp, #-16]!

    dummy .req x19
    mov dummy, x0
    num_bits .req w20
    mov num_bits, w1
    i .req w21
    mov i, #0

initialize_loop:
    cmp i, num_bits
    bgt initialize_loop_end

    mov w0, #1
    lsl w1, i, #2
    str w0, [dummy, w1, uxtw]

    add i, i, #1
    b initialize_loop

initialize_loop_end:

initialize_done:
    stp x21, x22, [sp], #16
    stp x19, x20, [sp], #16
    stp x29, x30, [sp], #16
    ret

    .unreq dummy
    .unreq num_bits
    .unreq i

edit_dummy:
    stp x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x19, x20, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x21, x22, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x23, x24, [sp, #-16]!

    dummy .req x19
    mov dummy, x0
    num_bits .req w20
    mov num_bits, w1
    i .req w21
    mov i, #0
    original .req x22
    mov original, x2
    neighbors .req w23
    mov neighbors, #0
    width .req w24
    mov width, w3

edit_dummy_loop:
    cmp i, num_bits
    bgt edit_dummy_loop_end

    mov w7, #0    // neighbor total -> w7

    // left neighbor = i-1
    mov x0, original
    mov w1, num_bits
    mov w2, i
    sub w2, w2, #1
    bl get_bit
    add neighbors, neighbors, w0

    // right = i+1
    mov x0, original
    mov w1, num_bits
    mov w2, i
    add w2, w2, #1
    bl get_bit
    add neighbors, neighbors, w0

    // up = i-width*32
    mov x0, original
    mov w1, num_bits
    mov w2, i
    lsl w3, width, #5
    sub w2, w2, w3
    bl get_bit
    add neighbors, neighbors, w0

    // down = i+width*32
    mov x0, original
    mov w1, num_bits
    mov w2, i
    lsl w3, width, #5
    add w2, w2, w3
    bl get_bit
    add neighbors, neighbors, w0

    // upper left = i-width*32-1
    mov x0, original
    mov w1, num_bits
    mov w2, i
    lsl w3, width, #5
    sub w2, w2, w3
    sub w2, w2, #1
    bl get_bit
    add neighbors, neighbors, w0

    // upper right = i-width*32+1
    mov x0, original
    mov w1, num_bits
    mov w2, i
    lsl w3, width, #5
    sub w2, w2, w3
    add w2, w2, #1
    bl get_bit
    add neighbors, neighbors, w0

    // bottom left = i+width*32-1
    mov x0, original
    mov w1, num_bits
    mov w2, i
    lsl w3, width, #5
    add w2, w2, w3
    sub w2, w2, #1
    bl get_bit
    add neighbors, neighbors, w0

    // bottom right = i+width*32+1
    mov x0, original
    mov w1, num_bits
    mov w2, i
    lsl w3, width, #5
    add w2, w2, w3
    add w2, w2, #1
    bl get_bit
    add neighbors, neighbors, w0

    cmp neighbors, #2
    blt underpopulated
    beq stay_the_same
    cmp neighbors, #3
    beq procreation
    bgt overpopulation

underpopulated:
    mov x0, dummy
    mov w1, num_bits
    mov w2, i
    mov w3, #0
    bl set_bit

    add i, i, #1
    b edit_dummy_loop

stay_the_same:
    mov x0, original
    mov w1, num_bits
    mov w2, i
    bl get_bit
    mov w4, w0
    mov x0, dummy
    mov w1, num_bits
    mov w2, i
    mov w3, w4
    bl set_bit

    add i, i, #1
    b edit_dummy_loop

procreation:
    mov x0, dummy
    mov w1, num_bits
    mov w2, i
    mov w3, #1
    bl set_bit

    add i, i, #1
    b edit_dummy_loop

overpopulation:
    mov x0, dummy
    mov w1, num_bits
    mov w2, i
    mov w3, #0
    bl set_bit

    add i, i, #1
    b edit_dummy_loop

edit_dummy_loop_end:


edit_dummy_done:
    ldp x23, x24, [sp], #16
    ldp x21, x22, [sp], #16
    ldp x19, x20, [sp], #16
    ldp x29, x30, [sp], #16
    ret

    .unreq dummy
    .unreq num_bits
    .unreq i
    .unreq original
    .unreq neighbors
    .unreq width

copy_values:
    stp x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x19, x20, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x21, x22, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x23, x24, [sp, #-16]!

    original .req x19
    mov original, x0
    dummy .req x20
    mov dummy, x1
    num_bits .req w21
    mov num_bits, w2
    width .req w22
    mov width, w3
    i .req w23
    mov i, #0

copy_values_loop:
    cmp i, num_bits
    bgt copy_values_loop_end

    // load dummy value at index i
    // store dummy[i] at original[i] for all i
    // return
    mov x0, dummy
    mov w1, num_bits
    mov w2, i
    bl get_bit

    mov w0, w7  // moves the result from get_bit into w7
    mov x0, original
    mov w1, num_bits
    mov w2, i
    mov w3, w7
    bl set_bit

    add i, i, #1

    b copy_values_loop

copy_values_loop_end:


copy_values_done:
    ldp x23, x24, [sp], #16
    ldp x21, x22, [sp], #16
    ldp x19, x20, [sp], #16
    ldp x29, x30, [sp], #16
    ret

    .unreq original
    .unreq dummy
    .unreq num_bits
    .unreq width
    .unreq i
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have been stuck for a while.

Comment: Just as in C, this error almost certainly means you have overrun an array, used memory after it was freed, freed it twice, or something along those lines.

Comment: Can you cut this down to a [mcve]?  Right now this is really the worst of both worlds.  It's so long that a person can't really read through it all, but you also don't have a main function so a person can't build and test it.

Comment: valgrind supports ARM64/Linux, so that would be another good tool - you'll get a message and backtrace on the very first instruction where your program does something invalid.  By the time you see the error message from `free`, the bug is probably far in the past.

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but at `life_return`, `initialize_done`, etc, don't you want to be doing *loads* instead of stores?  You want to pop your registers off the stack, but instead you're just copying their new contents into space that will soon be overwritten.

Comment: Let's check the math here.  Suppose `width` and `height` are both 16.  So then `size` will be 256, and `num_bits` will be (16 << 5) *16 = 8192.  You now calloc `size` number of 4-byte words, so 256*4 = 1024 bytes.  Your `initialize_loop` iterates `num_bits` times, writing a word each time, so it's going to write 8192*4 = 32768 bytes into a buffer that was only allocated for 1024.

Comment: Actually there's an off-by-one bug to boot: `initialize_loop` actually iterates `num_bits+1` times because your exit condition is `bgt`.  This is effectively the classic C bug `for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)`.  So in fact you are going to write 32772 bytes :)

Comment: To be honest I think you need to unit test your functions, and/or start with a simpler project.  You seem to be achieving the kind of bug density that you get by writing the whole program start-to-finish in one sitting, having some significant gaps in understanding and not testing anything.  The result is that you end up making the same mistakes over and over throughout the code, instead of fixing and learning from it the first time.  For instance, I believe that all your loops have that same off-by-one bug.